# Как ограничить количество новостей, выводимых на страницу

Tags: php, mysql

Начал создавать свой первый сайт. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: Нужно как-то ограничить количество новостей на одной странице. Новости из базы данных с помощью ORDER BY.

Comment: ORDER BY someFieldName LIMIT start, num

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Измени запрос к базе данных, добавив LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `name` LIMIT 0, 10
```

LIMIT вызывается с двумя параметрами - с какой записи начинать, и сколько выводить.
Попробуй так.

Comment: Спасибо, брат!

Comment: Спасибо в карму не плюсуется. ;)